# How do I make non-continuous colorbar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Using matplotlib, I want to make a colorbar like the one pictured here:

[image]

I want my colorbar to basically jump from 0 to 65/-65, then go linearly up to 100/-100. In other words, I want 65/-65 to be the dimmest colors (red/blue using seismic colormap) on the colorbar, 0 to be white, and 100/-100 to be the darkest colors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to use the `SymLogNorm`. It doesn't completely work out as it should; especially the tick locations seem to be a bit off. Maybe it can serve as a start for further experimentation.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import SymLogNorm
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import numpy as np

norm = SymLogNorm(linthresh=60, linscale=0.05, vmin=-100, vmax=100)
xs = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(xs, norm(xs))
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 21)
plt.scatter(x, norm(x), c=x, norm=norm, cmap='seismic', s=200, edgecolor='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap='seismic', norm=norm), pad=0.02)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticks([-100, -90, -80, -70, -60, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])
plt.xlabel('input value')
plt.ylabel('normalized value')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: visualizing SymLogNorm]

Here is a test with a `BoundaryNorm` using many subdivisions to counter its stepwise nature.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import numpy as np

ticks = [-100, -90, -80, -70, -60, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
bounds = np.r_[np.arange(-100, -59), np.linspace(-50, 50, 11), np.arange(60, 101)]
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, 256)
xs = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(xs, norm(xs))
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 21)
plt.scatter(x, norm(x), c=x, norm=norm, cmap='seismic', s=200, edgecolor='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap='seismic', norm=norm), pad=0.02, ticks=ticks)
plt.xlabel('input value')
plt.ylabel('normalized value')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: visualizing BoundaryNorm]